# Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class animation-list

Tags: android, error-handling, android-animation

i am trying to add animation to xml file which it's run when i call this class

```
public class anim extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.anim.anim);
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.anim.anim);
img.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.anim);
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
frameAnimation.start();
}
}
```

here is the xml file

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  >

<item android:drawable="@drawable/bee00" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bee01" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bee02" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bee03" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bee04" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bee05" android:duration="50" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/bee06" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/bee07" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/bee08" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bee09" android:duration="50" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/bee10" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

when i run my application

```
Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class animation-list
```

on the LogCat window any body know ??

Answer (score 0):

That's because you inflate your prefernce screen with content of Animation xml file, when you should use menu.xml file instead, like described in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html).

Also when you find specific view at a layout you should use it's id value saved in `R.id`

Than, if you want to use frame animation, you should create xml file and store it in `res/drawable` folder and than refernce to it in code, using `R.drawable.filename` when you set background resource for your image. Look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame) documentation too.

Answer (score 0):

The `.xml` file must start with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
        //your items
</animation-list>
```

and must be in the `res/drawable` directory.

Your images must be in the `res/drawable` directory too. The `animation.start()` must be called in the `onStart()` method

Here's the doc:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation

*Pd: Be sure not to use too big images, my device ran out of memory.*